# best mobile ecosphere for developers

Tags: mobile

Now that the Windows 8 development environment is here I am interested in an actual comparison of the three major mobile ecospheres; Windows Phone, IOS & Android, from a development perspective.

Objective things to consider are...

- The cost to buy in (price of Visual Studio, Apple Developers group, etc).
- The percentage of actual dollars spent on apps in each realm.
- The percentage of sales paid to the App Stores.
- The power of the development language in real terms such as lines of code, and number of classes to achieve similar functionality.
- The maintainability of software from OS release to release ( for example how easy is it to accommodate new screen resolutions ).
- The availability and completeness of mocking and testing frameworks libraries and IDE integration.

How friendly to developers are each and in what ways, based on measurable facts?